# Understanding lexical grammar for multi-line comments in JavaCC

Tags: lexical-analysis

I'm struggling to understand why this piece of lexical grammar works for multi-line comments in JavaCC (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550579/multiline-comments-in-javacc)):

```
 "/*" (~["*"])* "*" (~["*","/"] (~["*"])* "*" | "*")* "/"
```

As I read it, the parser scans the input /*, and then zero or more optional occurrences of * can appear, followed by a *, and then zero or more optional occurrences of * and /, then zero or more occurrences of * followed by * or *, ended by a /. Specifically, this part boggles my mind:

```
 (~["*","/"] (~["*"])* "*" | "*")*
```

I'd appreciate some help understanding this.

Comment: Try writing an expression yourself. Starts with /*, ends with */, and no */ in between.

Comment: In JavaCC, `~` is used to negate the following character class. So `~["*"]*` means "zero more characters *other than* `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write this in a more manageable way. I'll use $x$ for any symbol other than $/$ and $*$. Your expression is
$$
/* (/+x)^* * (x(/+x)^** + *)^* /
$$
Now let us apply the following identity to the part "$*(x(/+x)^**+*)^*$":
$$
r(sr)^* = (rs)^*r
$$
We get
$$
/* (/+x)^* (*x(/+x)^*+*)^* */
$$
It's clear what the outer parts $/*$ and $*/$ do, so let's focus on the inner part
$$
(/+x)^* (*x(/+x)^*+*)^*
$$
which captures all strings not containing the substring $*/$. Using the identity
$$
(rs+r)^* = (r^+s)^*
$$
we can simply it to
$$
(/+x)^* (*^+x(/+x)^*)^*
$$
Essentially, each run of stars is "guarded" by a following $x$.